# Python, Printing dictionary key dependent on value amount

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, key-value

I'm looking to print the key depending on the amount of values...

Lets say in my dictionary I have...

```
('l', 2)
('o', 1)
('h', 1)
('e', 1)
```

I would like to print this as

```
L, L, O, H, E
```

these characters can change in my code as they are user inputted.

Comment: `('l', 2) ('o', 1) ('h', 1) ('e', 1)` is not a dictionary.

Comment: Also, the dictionary elements are not ordered. So, you may not exactly get `L, L, O, H, E`, in the same order.

Comment: convert to dict: `my_dictionaryd = dict([('l', 2), ('o', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1)])`

Comment: it does sort descending order of values. But when i print it doesn't do duplicates?

Comment: `for key in dict:
        for i in range(dict[key]):
            print key`

Comment: @James_VW Please edit the question and include all the necessary details. Otherwise this question will be considered as low-quality and closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
alist = [('l', 2), ('o', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1)]
alist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print ', '.join(list(''.join([key.upper()*val for key, val in alist])))

## prints 'L, L, O, H, E'
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the dictionary and for each `Key` you will get its `value`. And print `key` that many number of times.

```
for key in dictionary.keys():
   value = dictionary[key]
   i = 0
   while i < value:
      print key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dictionary = dict([('l', 2), ('o', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 1)])
ans = ""

for key in my_dictionary:
    for rep in xrange(my_dictionary[key]):
        ans+=key+" ,"
print ans[:-2]   #To remove the trailing comma
```

Comment: Whilst this code may be correct, please could you leave more of an explanation as to how the OP could learn from this code in his example.